# Using Python shutil.copy to overwrite a file gives asyntax error

Tags: syntax, shutil

I am trying to overwrite one .png file with another using shutil.copy, but I keep getting a syntax error. The line in question is-

```
shutil.copy("/var/www/vk7krj/running/yoga.png", "/var/www/vk7krj/running/run4.png")
```

and the error is-

```
  File "./latlong4.py", line 63
    shutil.copy("/var/www/vk7krj/running/yoga.png","/var/www/vk7krj/running/run4.png")

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with an up-arrow under the l in shutil

I have "import shutil" and also "from shutil import copyfile" in the head of the file.
Several hours of google searching has turned up nothing, so any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved- turns out the error was incorrect indentation in an if-else earlier in the script- corrected that and the syntax error went away.